# Rest WEB service pool requests at one moment

Tags: php, web-services, rest, queue

I don't know did I make a correct caption of my question so feel free to correct me. So I have a REST web service written on PHP (It retreives some data from database and returns some xml data). I have tested it with JMeter and made a conclusion that it responses fast (min 50 requests per second with answer faster than 5 sec.) But in my log of requests I found that sometimes I recieve the pool of requests (means ~10-20 requests at one moment) and my service is unavailable to proceed all of them. What can I do. How can I handle them? How can I make some queue and response each of them separately. Thanks

Comment: I think that is the servers work and not the work of the webservice

Comment: as @JamesNjuguna sayed, maybe consider using another web server like **nginx** or use **php-fpm**

Comment: Somebody please post it like an answer to allow me to access is as solve answer